# How to add image or icon inside a GWT TextBox widget?

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to add image or icon inside a GWT TextBox widget?

**EDIT:** The image is required to have a ClickHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only interested in visually adding an icon , you can add it using css such as :

```
background-image:url('icon.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

**UPDATE :**

If you need to add events to image, you can bind an image and a textbox in a horizontal panel as in @Sandro Munda's answer. Also another method is to use an absolute panel and css to make the image and the textbox overlap as such :

```
public class TextBoxWithImage extends Composite {
    public TextBoxWithImage() {
        AbsolutePanel p = new AbsolutePanel();
        p.add(new TextBox());       
        Image image = new Image("images/down.png");
        image.getElement().getStyle().setMarginLeft(-20, Unit.PX);
        p.add(image);       
        image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert("Clicked!");
            }
        });
        initWidget(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: However I need to add ClickHandler to the image.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

You can extend an HorizontalPanel and create your new widget like the ValueSpinner class does (from the Gwt Mosaic project).

[ValueSpinner.java](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-mosaic/source/browse/branches/GWT-2.0/src/org/gwt/mosaic/ui/client/ValueSpinner.java)

As you can see, the ValueSpinner joins a TextBox and an Image inside a HorizontalPanel to create the widget.